# How can I see which packages were removed with apt-get autoremove?

Tags: apt

Despite claims that `autoremove` is safe, I have, more than once, removed important packages and then finding **what** was removed has been a struggle. How do I find out what was removed with this command post-facto?

Comment: You can check the `/var/log/dpkg.log`.

Comment: (same logs apply)

Comment: If the answers are the same but questions are different... is it still a dupe?

Comment: I edit the question so that it's more generic. Now it fits the bill.

Comment: What I don't understand with those questions: Why don't you read what will be removed **before** pressing <Enter> ?

Comment: @guntbert I did. Thought, hmm, *that*'s interesting. Next day when I turn my computer on, I had no xserver anymore. By then i couldn't remember which package had been removed

Comment: I got bit by this 'apt autoremove' "feature" as well. Yesterday, apt suggested that a whole slew of over a dozen packages be removed, including nvidia related drivers. Trusting that they knew what they were doing, I simply did an autoremove. After which, I had to reinstall Ubuntu in order to get my system working again.. And, on reflection, this has happened to me at least twice, over the years..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do:

```
grep remove /var/log/dpkg.log
```